# In R, display the character NULL to the default namespace in an XML node

Tags: r, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create an XML document in R using the XML package. The XML document must follow a specific schema, whereby a particular element/node displays the default namespace (xmlns) attribute as the character NULL ("").

From the XML package documentation (`?newXMLNamespace`), they provide the following example:

```
foo = newXMLNode("foo")
ns = newXMLNamespace(foo, "http://www.r-project.org")
foo
```

which yields

```
<foo xmlns="http://www.r-project.org"/>
```

whereas, I am looking for:

```
<foo xmlns=""/>
```

However, when I alter the example R syntax above to be:

```
foo = newXMLNode("foo")
ns = newXMLNamespace(foo, "")
foo
```

printing `foo` yields

```
<foo/>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.